# Another one for the road

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> Taken for a ride,
>   lost with many strides.
>
> Pardon the old port,
>   a typer's resort.
>   *OR*
>   Fight unworldly wrath,
>   sleep after a bath.
>
> Big bang creation?
>   Welcome inflation!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is:

> **spare tyre** or **spare tire**.

Taken for a ride, lost with many strides.

> The spare tyre sits in the boot and goes wherever the car goes. Many strides, that is excessive walking, can make you lose your "spare tyre" – the ring of spare fat around your waist.

Pardon the old port, a typer's resort.

> These two lines are wordplay: **Spare** (pardon) **Tyre** ([this old Phoenician port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyre,_Lebanon)); (**a typer's re**) "sorted" or rearranged gives **spare tyre**.

Fight unworldly wrath, sleep after a bath.

> Two lines of worplay again: **spar** (fight) + **et** (extraterrestrial, as Mea Cupla had already found out) + **ire** (wrath); **spa** (a bath) + **retire** (go to sleep).

Big bang creation? Welcome inflation!

> The spare tire comes into play when there was a "big bang" of one of the regular tires; keep it well inflated in case you need it.

And the title, of course, ...

> ... hints at the spare tyre's use: It's "another one for the road", in case one of the other four for the road is punctured.

Comment: Super! The second line hints at another more colloquail version of the ans.

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't know it was called that; we call it the "life belt".

Answer (score 3):

i think the answer is:

> Alcohol

Taken for a ride,

> Drinking too much alcohol generally makes one's head spin which is similar to being on a funfair ride (rollercoaster for example)

lost with many strides

> Being drunk and walking home could easily get one lost.

Pardon the old port,

> Port - a type of alcohol

a typer's resort.

> Many writers have alcohol abuse problems.

Fight unworldly wrath,

> Many people who are not generally considered angry or violent tend to get so when under the influence.

sleep after a bath.

> Possibly refers to the sound sleep you get when drunk.Many people sleep well after a long hot bath or shower.

Big bang creation?

> Alcohol is highly flammable and can lead to explosions. Could also be referring to the noise of a car accident as a result of driving under the influence.

Welcome inflation!

> Alcohol is generally an item that increases in price proportionate to inflation.

And the title

> refers to the last round before leaving a bar

Comment: Nice answer! I'm looking for another one which uses more wordplay.

Comment: haha unfortunately i can't see the wordplay answer at the moment. Thanks for the heads up as to why this current one is wrong! really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Well I guess it could be

> A spiral (track)

and explanation is here

Taken for a ride,

> Usually used for races (sprints / horse rides)

lost with many strides.

> racers may be losing with many strides apart

Pardon the old port,

> To be provided ...

a typer's resort.

> a type of 'record' (not necessarily a track record !!) where a typer is interested in

OR

```
Fight unworldly wrath,
```

> unworldly corresponds to Extra Terrestrial.. to be taken as **ET** or E twice (ee) leading to WRATH + EE = WREATHE - a type of curling/spiral motion

```
sleep after a bath.
```

> perhaps referring to resting after a sweat bath due to a race

```
Big bang creation?
```

> Universe was 'spiralled' out with a big bang as per scientists' theories

```
Welcome inflation!
```

> Inflation curves out / usually represented as a spiral

Comment: One fragment of this deduction is correct and is part of the answer (though there is a different answer from your nice one),

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is

> Time for a ride
>  Loosing time with strides
>  Old port and typers became outdated
>  Sleep time
>  Big bang created time
>  Inflation comes with time too

Comment: I can't make the spoilers work for some reason

Comment: make sure there is a line between your non spoiler text and the spoiler text

Comment: Spoiler markup is fiddly. All lines in a spoiler must be consecutive and begin with `>!`. And paragraph markup doesn't work inside spoilers; you must introduce hard line breaks by ending a line with two or more spaces.