# Word Slice Riddle #3

Tags: word, wordplay, rhyme

> With three i stay in line, 
>   With four I'll pick a fight,
>   With five i can wound or kill,
>   With all seven you can see my flight.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With three I stay in line

> row - in a line

With four I'll pick a fight

> spar - as in with a boxing partner

With five I can wound or kill,

> arrow - the straight headed weapon

With all seven you can see my flight.

> sparrow - the bird

Comment: and obviously you are correct, good job.. i have to ask, was it too easy?

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid, your puzzle is good and definite. Though a [tyrobrien](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me) type I was lucky as answered a [pre-Riley](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59943/what-am-i-answer-may-be-superfluous/59944#59944) and one of my [own](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54474/another-one-for-the-road)  which have the same start.